# Save multiple cakephp line

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

Hello I have 2 models Contracts and Services with a relationship.
I would like to save several lines of presentation the table looks like this:

```
 array(
    'files' => '',
    'Contract' => array(
        'client_id' => '324',
        'residence_id' => '1017',
        'name' => '',
        'beggin' => '',
        'end' => '',
        'content1' => '',
        'content2' => '',
        'content3' => '',
        'content4' => '',
        'content5' => '',
        'content6' => ''
    ),
    'Prestation' => array(
        'prestation' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'zone' => 'Bat A',
                'id_prestation' => array(
                    (int) 0 => '',
                    (int) 1 => '14'
                )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'zone' => 'Bat B',
                'id_prestation' => array(
                    (int) 0 => '',
                    (int) 1 => '10',
                    (int) 2 => '14'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'Statu' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'status' => 'proposed'
        )
    )
)
```

I try to save all the services in the contracts_prestation table which looks like this:
[prestations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5yvE.png)

```
public function add() {

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))
        {
            // TODO: Rewrite or remove the two next conditions when client and residences will be re-implemented.
            // SUPPRESSION DU CLIENT
            if (!empty($this->request->data['Contract']['client_id'])) {
                unset($this->request->data['Client']);
            } else {
                unset($this->request->data['Contract']['client_id']);
            }

            // SUPPRESSION DE LA RESIDENCE
            if (!empty($this->request->data['Contract']['residence_id'])) {
                unset($this->request->data['Residence']);
            } else {
                unset($this->request->data['Contract']['residence_id']);
            }

            // AJOUT DU STATUS
            $this->request->data['Statu'] = array( 0 => array( 'status' => 'proposed' ) );

            // AJOUT DU CONTRAT
            $this->Contract->create();
            $this->request->data['Contract']['is_active'] = false;
            if ($this->Contract->saveAll($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Contrat enregistré.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'contracts', 'action' => 'index'));
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Impossible d'enregistrer le devis."));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set( 'clients', $this->Client->find('list') );
            $this->set( 'residences', $this->Residence->find('list') );
            $this->set( 'prestations', $this->Prestation->find('list') );
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to find where is the problem with my relationship?

Do you think I forgot something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: any idea. i am blocked :(